# Using nested IF statements causing a "CS1513: } expected" error (C# in Webmatrix)

Tags: c#, webmatrix

Working on my first Web Pages project using C# and Webmatrix. So for thing have been going pretty well but have now run into an issue that has me stumped.
What I am doing is posting a form to this page which contains a message and I am then saving the message to the DB (and will later also get the email part going).

I've posted the code below, it's actually longer than need be to illustrate the problem but thought I'd post it all nonetheless. WebMatrix was already highlighting an issue at hand before I tried running it when I saw that the penultimate closing curly brackets was highlighted yellow. When running the code (and the post values are all OK) I get the error "CS1513: } expected". I initially thought I had by mistake added an extra closing curly bracket, but after checking and double checking and then slowly rebuilding up the code line by line to identify after which line it started going wrong, I have now come to the conclusion that without any of the nested "if" and "foreach" statements within the "if(IsPost && WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)" "if" statement that it then "works" (although obviously not with the desired logic).

I've checked around and I've found plenty of C# code examples where this is done. Any help, pointers or anything else much appreciated.

Q

```
@{
if(IsPost && WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated){
    var fromEmail = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName;
    var fromUserId = @WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
    var message = Request["message"];
    var uid = Request["uid"];
    bool multiSend = false;
    var db = Database.Open("Tennegize");

    var skillLevel = 0;
    if(Request["multi"]=="1"){
        multiSend = true;
    }

    //Save to message to BD
    var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Messages (UserEmail, UserId, Message) VALUES (@0, @1, @2)";
    db.Execute(insertQuery, fromEmail, fromUserId, message);
    decimal messageId = db.GetLastInsertId();

    if(multiSend){
         //Get email address' from all recipients
        var sql2 = "SELECT Email FROM UserProfile WHERE SkillLevel = @0";
        var data2 = db.Query(sql, skillLevel);
        var totalRecipents = data2.Count();
        //Log all recipients who will recieve this notification
        foreach(var recipient in data2){
            insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Message_Recipients (UserId, UserEmail, MessageId) VALUES (@0, @1, @2)";
            db.Execute(insertQuery, uid, data.Email, messageId); 
        }

    }else{
        // Get to recipients email address
        var sql = "SELECT Email FROM UserProfile WHERE UserId = @0";
        var data = db.QuerySingle(sql, uid);
        //Log the recipient of this norification
        insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Message_Recipients (UserId, UserEmail, MessageId) VALUES (@0, @1, @2)";
        db.Execute(insertQuery, uid, data.Email, messageId);

    }

    }
}
```

Comment: It presumably points to a line in your code -- what is that line?

Comment: Also, you **really** should not be putting logic like this in your views.

Comment: For some reason the listed line number does not match up with the line number in my code (it's about 2x higher than I even have lines of code), but seeing the code around it, it's saying it's the last closing brace.

Thanks for your comment about my placement of logic. I'm afraid this is my first real project after having just read "Beginning ASP.NET Web Pages with WebMatrix". Had a brief browse into MVC, but the concepts were a lot harder to grasp for me so decided to just stick to the "easier" way where I am getting results.

Comment: You opened a brace at `@{` that is never closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that the line `var fromUserId = @WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;` is causing the problem. Remove the `@` before `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId`.

Comment: No way! Was somehow blind to that "copy & paste" mistake!

Comment: I also had the same issue and thought it was related to nested if statements.  In my case, I'd added some extra @'s when using Webmatrix 2, but these aren't needed after upgrading to v3